# How do I get my domain unblocked by Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Through a lot of angst, it's quite apparent that Facebook does not like the URL I am using for my Facebook app `divine.ly`.

When I try to put the URL into the *Site URL* for the Facebook app, I get `Site URL invalid domain`

When I try to file a bug about this domain it is says `Content Blocked` and I can't even file a bug about this issue.

When my app tries to share a link e.g. `http://divine.ly`, the action fails with the error `The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)`

#### Here is what I know

- It's not just because it's a *.ly domain, I've tried bit.ly and it works fine
- It's not the IP address of my web server, I've used a different URL on the same server and that works fine
- I even tried a 301 redirect from another domain `divinely.org` --> `divine.ly`, this worked initially, but then `divinely.org` stopped working as well.

This site is brand new (not really even in production yet) and yet maybe the

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not customer support for your favourite company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got my URL back, so I'm posting this everywhere that I had searched for an answer:

Facebook blocked use of our URL for years, yes years. For some reason no one could include our website URL (a-fib.com) in any post, or even on our own FB page. They'd get an error message saying our site had been flagged as spammy. This had been going on for years! FB has zero customer service.

Here's what worked. After trying everything else over the course of three years, we finally resorted to writing a pleading letter on our letterhead, asking why would anyone block a non-profit trying to help heart patients? We sent it 'registered mail' to FB headquarters. (Advice I found among other ideas online from those with a similar problem.)  It worked. Praise the lord! Patti Ryan

Comment: thanks for the answer... I guess I would never have thought to write them a physical letter. It's sad that you really have no insight or recourse when your domain gets blocked.

Comment: It's been some time since I posted this solution. So glad it's still helping other FB users. Patti