# What do you do when Facebook blocks your URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

To reproduce:

1. Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
2. Type in allprowebtools.com
3. Submit

Error: This link is blocked, or you have triggered an excessive amount of scrapes. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.

**I am hoping someone out there can help me.**  Things I have done in efforts to correct this:

1. Clicked the "let us know" link
2. Talked to one of Facebook's sales representatives, she said she see's no obvious reason why this is happening
3. Perfected our open graph html tags
4. Registered and monitor for all major blacklisting companies, we have a good status on all I can find
5. Changed our IP address, for the record you can use the IP as the URL (http://54.68.7.197/) and the error changes to: Failed to get composer template data.
6. Opened Bug Ticket with Facebook was told to put this on this site: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/460783617337306/

If anyone has anything that can help, please help a fellow frustrated programmer out!

Comment: You really need to persist with Facebook representatives.  Get the sales dude to escalate your problem to someone who can investigate.  Either way, this is not really a programming problem.

Comment: Or follow the advice here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243644/which-stack-exchange-site-is-for-asking-about-facebook

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I forgot one thing that I have tried.  I have opened a bug report with facebook and they closed it and told me to put it on here, so I did.  I realize this isn't a strictly programming question, but if what is wrong is an open graph problem it is.  Bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/460783617337306/

Comment: You could also try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505186/how-do-i-get-my-domain-unblocked-by-facebook/18838247#18838247

Comment: Whoever did that is being UNHELPFUL ... and feel free to tell them I told you that!  Sure, your bug report was inappropriate ... unless you can point to something in the way that you use the Facebook APIs that triggered the blocking.  However, them sending you on a "wild goose chase" to StackOverflow is down right rude.  They **ought** to know that this is the wrong place.

Comment: P.S. - I can't read that bug report, and there's no way I'm going to sign up so that I can.  Yet another reason to bucket Facebook ... if you ask me.

Comment: I am going to try to write a letter, thank you for all of your input!

Comment: The bug tool you reported it in is for Facebook Developer questions. That your domain is blocked is not a Facebook Developer question.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is the same problem and the same error message, this seemed like an easier way to explain it that made what the actual problem was a little more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!  Since the time of my question I have:

1. Wrote a letter pleading to Facebook
2. Deleted an old hacked account
3. Asked 20 people to click the "let us know" link that appears when
   banned

Final solution that worked....

I started paying for post advertising on my page, nothing that went to the website.  One of the posts I really wanted to promote our new blog post so when I posted it I put the IP address in the URL instead of the TLD. Posted it, advertised it for $5, 10 minutes later we were unbanned!

Hopefully this answer helps someone else that is going through this hell!