# An internal error occurred while linting the URL. for my website

Tags: facebook

I test my url here :

`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/`

And get this error :

`This link is blocked, or you have triggered an excessive amount of scrapes. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.`

`Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed
Error Linting URL : An internal error occurred while linting the URL.`

I sent form report but after 10 days facebook not reply to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you do when Facebook blocks your URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389465/what-do-you-do-when-facebook-blocks-your-url)

Comment: @tomerpacific thank you. but your url not solved my problem